# Prove this smallest sigma field

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $\Omega = \{1,2,3,...\}$ and define $\mathcal{C}_{j}=\{\Lambda : \Lambda \subset\{1,2, \ldots j\}\}$, show that 
>   $$
> \sigma(C_j) =  \mathcal{C}_{j} \cup\left\{\Lambda \cup\{j+1, j+2, \ldots\} : \Lambda \in \mathcal{C}_{j}\right\}
> $$

I can show that $\sigma(C_j)$ is sigma field.But how to show it is smallest?

Actually, I don't know general step to prove such kinds of problem when given specific smallest sigma field generated by specific collection of subsets. Any hint?

Comment: Start by showing that $\sigma(C_j)$ is in fact a sigma field. If we write $D_j = \{\Lambda \cup \{j+1, j+1, \ldots\} : \Lambda \in C_j\}$, then the complements of elements of $C_j$ are in $D_j$, and vice versa. What about closure under countable unions? What does $\cup A_i$ look like if all of the $A_i$'s are in $C_j$? How about if at least one of the $A_i$'s is in $D_j$?

Comment: @Bungo I can show that $\sigma(C_j)$ is sigma field.But how to show it is smallest?

Comment: Show that any sigma field containing $C_j$ must contain $\sigma(C_j)$. This is easy, because any sigma field containing $C_j$ must also contain $D_j$ as these are the complements of the sets in $C_j$.

Comment: @Bungo Thanks!I got it.